# How do I make a delete and replace batch for a file in a folder?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to build a batch that will delete and replace a file with the same name.

I tried building a batch file where it deletes the file in the folder but I dont know how to go about replacing it with the same file name.

del "E:\easyad\ad.mp3"

My batch is unfinished and I am stuck

Comment: what do you want to replace it with?  Is there another file?  I can't tell you how much this sounds like malware.

Comment: no its not malware I didnt want to put my real file tree up. I want to delete it and replace it with a file of the same name. They are audio ads but i need them to be the same name when the one is deleted and replaced with a file of the same name

Comment: You don't need to delete anything then, just `copy`/`xcopy`/`robocopy`/`move` it using the appropriate option/switch to allow overwriting any existing file with the same name.

Comment: could you give me an example of how to do this I am stuck.